# Need to double-click on the checkbox to check

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I have problem, my code does not accept one cliques. It is necessary to click twice to put a tick.
If you click on the checkbox once, the tick does not appear, but if you click the "Save" button, after the page is reloaded, the tick is on this checkbox.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = [];

$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function (event) {

    // This was your original function which sets the checkbox as checked or unchecked, and draws the check mark
    var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
        val = $target.attr('data-value'),
        $inp = $target.find('input[type="checkbox"]'),
        idx;

    if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
        options.splice(idx, 1);
        setTimeout(function () { $inp.prop('checked', false) }, 0);
    } else {
        options.push(val);
        setTimeout(function () { $inp.prop('checked', true) }, 0);
    }

    $(event.target).blur();

    // This code is used to set the selection[] hidden input to true when the checkbox is checked 
    // and to false when the check mark is cleared
    $tap = $target.find('input[name*="selection"]');
    if ($inp.prop("checked")) {
        $tap.val('true');
    } else {
        $tap.val('false');
    }

    return false;
});

var length = $('.dropdown-menu > option').length;

var cb = $('.dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked'); // Selected chechboxes
var cnt = $('.CompNameBox'); // Container where to output text
if (cb.length === 1)
    cnt.text(cb.parent().text());
else if (cb.length > 1)
    cnt.text('Selected ' + cb.length + ' companies');
else if (cb.length === 0)
    cnt.text('Nothing selected');
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="btn-group" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 180px"> <span class="CompNameBox"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 180px">
                    @if (Model.AvailableCompanies != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Model.AvailableCompanies.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (Model.Companies.Contains(Model.AvailableCompanies[i], new CompanyViewModelComparer()))
                            {
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked />&nbsp;@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => Model.AvailableCompanies[i].NAME)
                                    <input type="hidden" name="selection[@i]" value="true"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ids[@i]" value="@Model.AvailableCompanies[i].ID" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => Model.AvailableCompanies[i].NAME)
                                    <input type="hidden" name="selection[@i]" value="false" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ids[@i]" value="@Model.AvailableCompanies[i].ID" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            }

                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML from Chrome**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="btn-group open">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 180px" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="CompNameBox">Selected 2 companies</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 180px">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">&nbsp;TOro
                                    <input type="hidden" name="selection[0]" value="true">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ids[0]" value="1">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;My Comp
                                    <input type="hidden" name="selection[1]" value="false">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ids[1]" value="2">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">&nbsp;France
                                    <input type="hidden" name="selection[2]" value="true">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ids[2]" value="3">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Germany Corp
                                    <input type="hidden" name="selection[3]" value="false">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ids[3]" value="4">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need double click, why don't you use `dblclick`? In your code, you are using `click`.

Comment: @HTCom Please read the question.

Comment: If you can add the rendered HTML instead of the ASP(I assume its ASP) loop, it will be helpful.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I add Html

Comment: I think problem is in another place. Need click two time only one time. If you put/remove tick after that all work perfectly.

Comment: The problem is that you should never put interactive elements inside one another. In this case, an <input> inside an <a>. It causes confusion and is not semantical or syntactical. You should rearrange your HTML.

Comment: The issue you have here is because of 2 things. All the `a`  tags have same value in the `data-value` attribute. Next is that you are not setting value for the `options` array with already checked elements in the html. see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o410a8p/)

Comment: @MrLister can you help my with some code example how I can solve this problem?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I try use this, but it don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem occurs in `var options = []`, there is no value when initializing, but some input tags in your html code are already checked. So when you click the first time, js function can't take this tag from options. Remove from collection. Please modify the initialization method of options collection.